# onBackPressed() crashes my webview app

Tags: java, android, webview, onbackpressed

I am new to android development, I have tried to override onBackPress() to implement webView.GoBack(). But on pressing back key my apps getting crashed. Here is my MainActivity.java code. Am I doing something wrong ??

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView webview;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    public void onBackPressed (){

        if (webview.isFocused() && webview.canGoBack()) {
                webview.goBack();
        }
        else {
               super.onBackPressed();

        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        view.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient());
        view.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);


        view.loadUrl("http://url");


    }



    private class MyCustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

           view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }


        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            //hide loading image
            findViewById(R.id.imageLoading1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //show webview
            findViewById(R.id.webView).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }


        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            if (view.canGoBack()) {
                view.goBack();
            } else {
                view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
            }
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), description, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: But on pressing back key my apps getting crashed. what exception you got on going back ?

Comment: "crashed" means there's an error message in Logcat, so please post the error message

Comment: show us the logcat output please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because your `webView` is null. You are not referencing it anywhere. Modified your code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { 

private WebView view;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */ 

    public void onBackPressed (){ 

        if (view.isFocused() && view.canGoBack()) {
            view.goBack();
        } 
        else { 
            super.onBackPressed(); 
        } 
    } 


    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        view.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient());
        view.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);


        view.loadUrl("http://url");


    } 



    private class MyCustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override 
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

           view.loadUrl(url);
            return true; 
        } 


        @Override 
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            //hide loading image 
            findViewById(R.id.imageLoading1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //show webview 
            findViewById(R.id.webView).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } 


        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            if (view.canGoBack()) {
                view.goBack();
            } else { 
                view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
            } 
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), description, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } 

    } 
}
```

Comment: Huh! my bad, I did not notice that. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In `onCreate` you have:

```
WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
```

The WebView you have defined at the top has not been initialized, and is the one being used by the `onBackPressed` method, to fix this all you need to do is remove `WebView` before initializing the variable in `onCreate`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    view.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient());
    view.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);


    view.loadUrl("http://url");


}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton 4warded, I am new to SO and dont have enough reputation to upvote. :D

Comment: No problem, the accepted answer is pretty much the same as what I wrote, but I included more detail on what the actual problem was. Also, you can still upvote, but they only show when you get enough reputation :P

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can not do directly inside the fragment. The onBackPressed can be overridden in the FragmentActivity. What you can do is:

```
1.Override the onBackPressed inside the activity.
2.When the onBackPressed is called, check if the instance of the current fragment is the instance showing the webview.
3.If it is, ask the fragment if the webview can go back.
4.If it is not, call the super or whatever you need

 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
   Fragment webview = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("webview");
   if (webview instanceof MyWebViewFragment) {
          boolean goback = ((MyWebViewFragment)webview).canGoBack();
          if (!goback)
            super.onBackPressed();
   }
 }
```